# How to publish two services with same path but different URLs on Mule 3.2

Tags: servlets, mule, esb, endpoint, inbound

My need is to publish two services with same path on mule, but different URL's. Like this

```
https://localhost:8443/etc/app/version1/Service

https://localhost:8443/etc/app/version2/Service
```

Im using servlet mapping on web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>muleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And tried to use two different connectors since the path attribute doesn't allow me to use "version1/Service" or "version2/Service"

```
<servlet:connector
    name="conectorVersion1"
    servletUrl="https://localhost:8443/etc/app/version1/">
</servlet:connector>

<servlet:connector
    name="conectorVersion2"
    servletUrl="https://localhost:8443/etc/app/version2/">
</servlet:connector>
```

And finally, the endpoints

```
   <flow
    name="FlowVersion1"
    processingStrategy="synchronous">

       <servlet:inbound-endpoint
        connector-ref="conectorVersion1"
        path="Service">
        <-- processors, jaxws-service, interceptors etc.. -->
       </servlet:inbound-endpoint>
    </flow>

   <flow
    name="FlowVersion2"
    processingStrategy="synchronous">

       <servlet:inbound-endpoint
        connector-ref="conectorVersion2"
        path="Service">
        <-- processors, jaxws-service, interceptors etc.. -->
       </servlet:inbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
```

But i got this exception:

```
 [[/etc]] StandardWrapper.Throwable: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
 There are at least 2 connectors matching protocol "servlet", so the connector to use must be 
 specified on the endpoint using the 'connector' property/attribute. 
 Connectors in your configuration that support "servlet" are: conectorVersion1, conectorVersion2,
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's valid to declare two servlet connectors: there's only one servlet context so a single connector is enough. Actually, I *never* declare the Servlet connector, as the default configuration works just fine.

So with only the following configuration:

```
<flow name="FlowVersion1" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <servlet:inbound-endpoint
        path="version1/Service" />
    <set-payload value="version 1" />
</flow>

<flow name="FlowVersion2" processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <servlet:inbound-endpoint
        path="version2/Service" />
    <set-payload value="version 2" />
</flow>
```

I'm able to deploy in a servlet container (Jetty) and I can hit `/{context}/app/version1/Service` and `/{context}/app/version2/Service` without problem.

Comment: Thanks David, i already have discovered this and it worked, i was about to post my awnser but now i'll just accept yours. I'm just curious about something: do you know why paths that contain underscore only works with a slash as the first character? e.g this <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="service_v1_01_01/Hello"> doesnt work  but this <servlet:inbound-endpoint path="/service_v1_01_01/Hello"> works just fine

Comment: It looks like a bug to me: behind the scene Mule represent endpoints as URI and seems to consider `servlet://service_v1_01_01/Hello` and `servlet://service_v2_01_01/Hello` as conflicting, while `servlet:///service_v1_01_01/Hello` and `servlet:///service_v2_01_01/Hello` not... open a JIRA :D

Comment: Here it is: http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6638 And thanks again David.